# How to find current URL and change CSS rule?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to find current url and if it is equal to "http://localhost/mysite" then I need to put below code.

Example (pseudocode):

```
If(FindCurrentURL.ContainsString("http://localhost/mysite")){
  .ms-quickLaunch {  display: none; }
}
```

How to find URL and that contains above URL?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the current URL in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406192/how-to-get-the-current-url-in-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full current URL can be found in

```
window.location.href
```

the second part of your question is not as easy to implement as it seems. There are several ways to modify a CSS class during runtime, but none of them is really convenient and simple.

Consider targeting whatever element you want to hide using an ID and `document.getElementById()`.

Answer (score 2):

The `window.location.href` property will contain your current URL, which you can then test against in your if statement:

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf('http://localhost/mysite') >= 0){
    // do something fancy
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to change the CSS rule. Just select all the elements of that class and hide them via JavaScript.

For example, in jQuery:

```
$(".ms-quickLaunch").hide();
```